# limit excel inserted data to cell even if timestamp is equal

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, google-forms

i've create Google Form for class seats registration im using FormRanger AddOn to limit the capacity of registration to 6 for example and it work well.
my problem is  when 10 people register as the same timestamp for example 10:00:01 the formRanger AddOn register all of them and put my "Available seat " in minus...

pleas advise how can i write function that maybe can compare the number of seats at the same timestamp

thanks!!!

Comment: do you have milliseconds in your data? And are you sure this is a question for Excel since you refer to Google forms?

Comment: yes, i have milliseconds in my data.. all google Form data and Form Ranger AddOn factions made and inserted to Excel... bacause of that i think is connected to ecxel but i know that there is script editor in the excel online so also Code solution can be good  Thank you for your reply

Comment: well, I'm not familiar with FormRanger but do know that both Excel and Google sheets have a formula called `SMALL()` which will effectively allow you to pinpoint the first six entries by looking at the milliseconds. Don't know if that will be enough for your use case though.

Comment: i think in my case Small () will not help because every registration insert to the excel count to a cell that is limited to 6  and if 10 people press uibmit at the same millisecond the excel formula cannot restrict the press and choose the six first people since they are on the same timestamp

Comment: do you know what is the exact function to change automatically the date and time in timestamp to be with milliseconds i just see that i dont have milliseconds

Comment: Dates are stored as numbers in both excel and google sheets, days are the integers and decimals tell you the hours, minutes and seconds. So if you format as a number with enough decimals you should see them I think